# Questions on tf.layers .dense

Tags: python, tensorflow

I just started to study tensorflow recently. When doing some exercises, a question come up. 
For building hidden layers,there are two ways as I know to define.

1. By using tf.layers.dense, to define fully connected layer 
   e.g.

   layer_1=tf.layers.dense(X,512,activation=tf.nn.relu)
   layer_2=tf.layers.dense(layer_1,256,activation=tf.nn.relu)
2. By using tf.add(tf.matmul(X,W),b), a direct matrix multiply, to define layer
   e.g.:

   w1= tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([in_size, out_size]))

   b1=....

   w2=....

   b2=...

   layer_1=tf.add(tf.matmul(x,w1),b1)
   layer_1=tf.nn.relu(relu)
   layer_2=tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1,w2),b2)
   layer_2=tf.nn.relu(layer_2)

I tried these two ways to build a multilayer NN, both can work. 
My quesiton:is there difference between them? 
my guess: 1) In approach 2, W, b can be monitored by tensorboard since they are explicitly defined.

Appreciated for any feedback. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your first approach will use `tf.glorot_uniform_initializer` for initializing weights by default as mentioned in [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/dense) and [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/get_variable), so there might be slight difference in performance. I think you can monitor weights using first approach as well.

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely no difference between using `tf.layers` and defining your own layers by creating `W` and `b` matricies and then doing `tf.matmul` and `tf.add`. For example, the first snippet:

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
tf.set_random_seed(42)
X = tf.ones((5,4), dtype=tf.float32)
init = tf.initializers.random_uniform(minval=-0.1, maxval=0.1, dtype=tf.float32)
logits_first = tf.layers.dense(inputs = X, units = 7, kernel_initializer=init, 
bias_initializer=init)
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
sess.run(logits_first)
```

evaluates to the same values as the second snippet:

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
tf.set_random_seed(42)
X = tf.ones((5,4), dtype=tf.float32)
W = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([4, 7], -0.1, 0.1), dtype=tf.float32)
b = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([7], -0.1, 0.1), dtype=tf.float32)
logits_second = tf.add(tf.matmul(X, W), b)
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
sess.run(logits_second)
```

Besides, you can monitor both approaches. Everything that is defined within the graph creation can be monitored in tensorboard.